# Budget planning for students

Tags: united-kingdom, budget, student-loan

I hope this question is a good fit for the site.

So, I have just been accepted at a university (UK) and being 18 I don't have much experience planning budgets and certainly not for anything longer than a month.

I'm looking for an application (preferably web based) that will allow me to plan and manage my money. What I would consider desirable in said application is:

- Being web-based so that it can be accessed from any OS.
- Having Android app would certainly be a perk.
- Being time based - I want to be able to look exactly at which point in time I should have how much money - according to the calculations. I found many applications (e.g. [Brightside](http://studentcalculator.org.uk)) but they do not offer this - instead they allow you to input weekly/monthly/yearly income/outcome and calculate budget according to that. I'd prefer to be able to work more like a 'calendar'.

[Mint](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/) looks nice (from reviews) but I can't access it in UK. I'd appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Uh, have you tried google docs? Start off simple.

Other than that, for the moment I use GNUCash. Some day I might try to write my own, but for now it works well enough. I have a number of scheduled transactions in GNUCash, and it records them days in advance. You talk about "I should have how much money", but GNUCash offers a slightly better format: Future Minimum Balance. If you want to know whether you can spend money in an account without triggering a chain reaction, that's the number you want.

> Being web-based so that it can be accessed from any OS.

GNUCash is cross platform, with Windows, OSX and Linux clients. It also supports mysql/postgres database backends, so while it's not "Web based", you can keep your data "in the cloud".

Comment: Care to share why you downvoted, downvoter?

Comment: Whoever downvoted I don't think should have - just personal option. +1 for your efforts :) After trying out multiple websites, the closest I got to what I wanted was [PocketSmith](http://www.pocketsmith.com/) (although sadly its paid past 6 months into the future). I ended up using Excel spreadsheet (+ google drive/docs to fit into cloud base requirement). I will leave the question open for one more day; if no better options fitting the requirement pop up I'll accept yours as it's what I will end up using :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[MoneyDashboard](http://www.moneydashboard.com/) or [XeroPersonal](https://www.xero.com/personal/)  are similar sites to Mint.com

MoneyDashboard is planning on [releasing an Android App](http://help.moneydashboard.com/entries/20690813-moneydashboard-ios-android-app)

XeroPersonal is also in [development of an Android App](https://community.xero.com/personal/discussion/291/)

For more details about the differences between the two apps, see [this Web App question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa)

Comment: I have tried MoneyDashboard extremely slow and buggy beyond belief. Other than that it's not all that bad. Will check XeroPersonal and see how that goes :) For now +1 for a good answer adressing my problem :) Thanks.